# How to check a child application name from Task Manager using a bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, tasklist

I want to check a particular application name from the Task Manager using a bat file. I have opened three word document files and from the Task Manager I can see the process as shown in the below image.

[image]

In the Task Manager there are 3 documents open under Microsoft Word application.

```
Microsoft Word(3)
 - temp 1
 - temp 2
 - temp 3
```

Now I want to write a bat file to close the particular word document (e.g.: temp 2). I am just trying to kill the particular word document name using `tasklist` function.

As per the Microsoft documentation  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist, I can get the IMAGENAME , WINDOWTITLE etc. How can I get a particular child name (temp 2) under the parent (Microsoft Word) from the Task Manager process tab?

Comment: Is `temp# - Word` not the WindowTitle?

Comment: @Compo 'temp#' is the word document name but in task manger it is showing 'temp# - Word' .

Comment: if i am using WINDOWTITLE like this `taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq temp2 - Word" /T` will do the job ? but i am still doubt like how can i check the parent process name (Microsoft Word) ?

Comment: You can use multiple filters or additionally include `/IM` with `/FI`, please open a Command Prompt window and enter `taskkill /?` to see the options available.